ビルドしたゲームの表示が単色の正方形のみになる
プロジェクトをビルドして実行を行うと、こんな感じの画面が表示されるようになってしまいました。効果音は鳴り、シーン以降やコマンドの操作はできているような感じがあるのですが、画面だけおかしいです。シーンが動くと表示色も変わります。ビルドではなくUnity内での操作では正しく動作しています。
発生経緯
ディスコードで通話しながらOBSでビルドした画面の収録を行おうとしたら紫色が表示され、再起動をかけたらこのような感じになりました。
環境
Mac M2
試した対処

ビルドを新しく作る
Unityの再起動
PCの再起動


